# Bound on variance

Tags: integration, inequality, variance

I would like some help with my homework assignment.

I do not expect a full solution but i do not know where to even start.

[image]

How do i even start with part a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to show (a):

You have $P(\{X\geq b\})=\beta$

Note that $x^2$ is a increasing function when $x\geq 0$ and $b>0$. Then $\inf \{x^2:b\leq x<\infty\}=b^2$

$$\int_b^\infty x^2f_X(x)\,dx\geq b^2\int_b^\infty f_X(x)\,dx=b^2P(\{X\geq b\}) =b^2\beta$$

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand this how did you manage to remove the x^2

Comment: My bad I understood it now. Thanks

Comment: you are welcome @aceminer

Comment: Can I just confirm that the integration of f(x) gives u beta But the thing is integration of f(x) gives cdf. But in this case it is Pr(x>b)

Comment: b? $P(\{X\geq b\})=\beta$ given, isn't?

Comment: yes but in the question it is f(x)

Comment: @aceminer $f_X(x)$ is the pdf or pmf here. I guess you know $\int_{-\infty}^{c}f_X(x)dx=P(X\leq c)$ by definition.

Comment: yes I do. But how does it apply. Sorry I am extremely new to this.

Comment: @aceminer $\int_{c}^{\infty}f_X(x)dx=1-\int_{-\infty}^{c^-}f_X(x)dx=1-P(X\leq c^-)=P(X\geq c)$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int_b^\infty x^2 f_X(x)\,dx & \ge \int_b^\infty b^2 f_X(x)\,dx & & \text{because } x^2\ge b^2 \text{ when } x\ge b >0 \\[10pt]
& = b^2\beta & & \text{by the definition you gave for } \beta.
\end{align}